# Communication between Cordova plugins

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am working on an app which should receive gcm pushes and append the payload info, which contains geofence data, to a list of geofeneces.

To get this job done, I use these Plugins:

[Cordova PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)

[Cordova Geofence](https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence)

Everything is working fine when the app is opened or minimized. But when the user closes the app, received pushes are displayed as notification. This is not what I want. I want to receive pushes always silent to append them to geofences.

I know that I can't run javascript code, when the app is closed. Therefore I was thinking about if it is able to let both plugins communicate with each other in java.

Like this:

GCM Push -> PushPlugin receives push -> sends data to GeofencePlugin -> Geofence gets added to device

Is that possible?

Comment: you can create your own plugin that handles the code for both cases

Comment: isn't it possible just to add some code to the PushPlugin, so that this plugin tells the GeofencePlugin to add new data to Storage?